# how to upload the images and save it to database using react

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, express, mern

I am designing profile page for my site using MERN stack. Now my question is how do I upload the image from local machine and save it to the database and also displaying it in the profile page

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: just uploading the profile image and save it

Comment: Did you succeed the task Mr.Navin Prasad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multer for images upload.
Check out this [article](https://medium.com/ecmastack/uploading-files-with-react-js-and-node-js-e7e6b707f4ef) for code examples.